# python2.7 minimal error on xenial

Tags: apt, python-2.7

I'm trying to fix python2.7 installation on Ubuntu 16.04. I keep getting the following error:

```
Fetched 1,440 kB in 0s (3,482 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 98454 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
new installation of python2.7-minimal; /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages is a directory
which is expected a symlink to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
please find the package shipping files in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages and
file a bug report to ship these in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead
aborting installation of python2.7-minimal
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython-stdlib_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.11-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried

sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt update

Can someone help me out? 
Thanks.

UPDATE:
When I try sudo apt -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 150 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,432 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,320 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 98458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
new installation of python2.7-minimal; /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages is a directory
which is expected a symlink to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
please find the package shipping files in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages and
file a bug report to ship these in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead
aborting installation of python2.7-minimal
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try just installing Python 2. It should install the latest version. Don't specify a version number.  `sudo apt-get install python2`

Comment: its unable to locate the package python2

Comment: As far I know the package is simply called python and not python2 on 16.04. `apt-cache search python` will give you a list of all available packages, and there are packages beginning with python3 (which is in fact python 3.5) and python (which is python 2.7).

Comment: `sudo apt install python` , give the following error The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-minimal : Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: What you want to do is do: "sudo apt-get install python2.7-minimal"  without the quotes. And if that doesn't work  do "sudo apt-get -f install" (without quotes) and then do "sudo apt-get install python2.7-minimal ; sudo apt-get install python"

Comment: "sudo apt-get -f install" and "sudo apt-get install python2.7-minimal" both return the error in OP's question, and "sudo apt-get install python" returns the dependency error described 2 comments above.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try running

```
mv /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages; ln -s dist-packages /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Which fixed a similar issue for me in Docker.
Inspired by https://forums.swift.org/t/lldb-install-precludes-installing-python-in-image/24040